# How do I replicate the behavior of this bottom panel in react native?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, mobile, scroll, user-experience

[image]

There's a bottom panel that covers 1/3 of the screen when you first open the Lyft app. You can slide the panel up or tap on "search destination" and the panel will slide all the way up, snap to the top and become a full screen. Sliding down or pressing cancel will revert the app back to its initial state with the bottom panel covering 1/3 of the screen

Answer (score 0):

There is some amazing libs that can help you:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sliding-up-panel
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sliding-up-down-panel

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

For replicate the behavior of bottom panel in react native you can use:

https://docs.nativebase.io/action-sheet